# create a FID column in shapefile in ogr or geopandas python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, osgeo

I need the information of the FID column from a shapefile. Somehow that column is not "shown" when you load shapefile. I need the information of that column because I need to say something like:

| fid | id | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | forest |
| 2 | 1 | forest |
| 3 | 2 | water |
| 4 | 2 | water |
| 5 | 3 | urban |

I need to know which fids belong to ids X,Y,Z, etc. I tried the following in geopandas. Is there a more efficient way of doing it using geopandas or OGR from osgeo? Thanks

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
from osgeo import ogr

# open the training data
train_cl_fn = os.path.join(src, "train.shp")

# read the column "id" that already exists. This id column says that feature X belongs to id Y
X_train_G = gpd.read_file(train_cl_fn)
class_ids = X_train_G["id"].unique()
print('class ids: ', class_ids)

# I create an empty array for the fids
class_fids = np.array([])
print('class labels: ', class_fids)

# add "fidl" column, using "id" and the empty array
# FID and fid are the same, therefore "fidl"
X_train_G['fidl'] = X_train_G['id'].map(dict(zip(class_ids, class_fids)))
print(X_train_G.head())

# export: rewrite file
X_train_G.to_file(os.path.join(src, "train.shp"))

# open the SAME file again, this time in ogr
train_cl_fn = os.path.join(src, "train.shp")
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
train_ds = driver.Open(train_cl_fn, 1) # 0 means read-only. 1 means writeable.
layer = train_ds.GetLayer()

for Ft in layer:
    ThisID = int(Ft.GetFID())
    #print('id is {}'.format(ThisID))
    Ft.SetField('fidl',ThisID)          # Write the FID to the fidl field
    layer.SetFeature(Ft)              # update the feature
dataSource = None  # save/rewrite file with fid info in the fidl column
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ogrinfo` from the command line to add a column in two simple steps:

```
ogrinfo train.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE layer ADD COLUMN fid1 integer" 
ogrinfo train.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE layer set fid1 = rowid"
```

Just make sure to use the correct name for the table (I used here `layer`), you can run ogrinfo train.shp to check what is the actual name of the layer(s) in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... after reading a bit, I found one more efficient way of doing it.

```
import os
from osgeo import ogr

src = "C:/path/"

#### Read SHP and create X_train_x segments array ####
# open training data
train_cl_fn = os.path.join(src, "train.shp")
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
train_ds = driver.Open(train_cl_fn, 1) # 0 means read-only. 1 means writeable.
layer = train_ds.GetLayer()

fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn('fidl', ogr.OFTReal) 
fieldDefn.SetWidth(14) 
fieldDefn.SetPrecision(6)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

for Ft in layer:
    ThisID = int(Ft.GetFID())
    #print('id is {}'.format(ThisID))
    Ft.SetField('fidl',ThisID)          # Write the FID to the fidl field
    layer.SetFeature(Ft)              # update the feature
dataSource = None
```

Do you know an even better way of doing this?